# forEach array, if value is odd remove from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all the even numbered items from my array with this code:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];  

myArray.forEach(function(item) {    
  if (item%2 == 0) {
    myArray.splice(item); 
  } 
});
```

I think where im getting it wrong is with the splice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];  

myArray.forEach(function(item, x) {    
  if (item%2 == 0) 
    myArray.splice(x, 1); // Remove 1 item from index x
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/vqf6j6ce/)

Or the better way to use `.filter` (IE8+)

```
var myArray = myArray.filter(function(item) {    
      return item % 2 ==0  ?  false  :  true; // Return false if item is even and true other way round.
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/vqf6j6ce/1/)

Answer (score 4):

you can do like this :

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  filtered = myarray.filter(function(el, index) {
    return index % 2 === 1;
  });
```

output : [2, 4, 6]

Answer (score 2):

yes, splice is done by index

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];  

myArray.forEach(function(item) {    
  if (item%2 == 0) {
   var index = myArray.indexOf(item); 
    myArray = myArray.splice(index,1); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter()` would be better

```
  var arr = myArray.filter(function(item) {    
      return item % 2 ==0  ?  true  :  false;
   });
```